# EPPlus - prevent whitespace characters from getting trimmed

Tags: epplus

In epplus, when I assign a string containing trailing whitespace, e.g.

```
myWorksheet.SetValue(1, 1, "Test ");
```

The space at the end gets removed from the cell when I save and open the file (it becomes `"Test"`). For my purposes I need to keep the trailing space. How can I prevent this from occurring?

Comment: That seems to work for me.  Are you sure the space is not there?  If you open the xlsx in 7zip or something, look at the sharedSring.xml file.  I see this:  `<t xml:space="preserve">Test </t>`

Comment: @Ernie - Can you toggle this functionality in epplus?